# Tinymce error in IE8 - 'p[...][...]' is null or not an object

Tags: tinymce

I am getting below error. Does anyone know what's the root cause and how to solve it ? I am using tinymce in IE8.

```
JS Error Message: 'p[...][...]' is null or not an object
```

I get this error in IE8 when i try to move away from page.

Comment: To be precise, in IE8 debugger is stopping at p[s][r.type].nativeHandler(r)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed with latest version of Tinymce.